# Given 3 vectors, how would I form the following array by vectorisation?

Tags: matlab

I have the following 3 vectors:

```
C =

 8
 9
10
14
15
16
20
21
22


R =

14
15
16
20
21
22
25
26
27


L =

 3
 4
 5
 8
 9
10
14
15
16
```

the numbers in these arrays run from 1 to d, where d is an integer.

I would like to form a d x d array such that the following pattern is satisfied:

```
Row 8 of O should have non-zero columns 8,14,3 such that
O(8,8) = 1
O(8,14) = 2
O(8,3) = -1

Row 9 of O should have non-zero columns 9,15,4.
O(9,9) = 1
O(9,15) = 2
O(9,4) = -1

...
```

with zeros everywhere else.

Essentially, I would like to optimize

```
for i = 1:length(C)
    A(C(i),[R(i) C(i) L(i)]) = [1 2 -1]; 
 end
```

Comment: And what value should the other elements in the array have?

Comment: And another question/annotation: C, R and L all contain the value 14; so the three conditions O(14,14)=1, O(14,14)=2 and O(14,14)=(-1) cannot be satisfied?

Comment: the other elements should be zero. Perhaps I have not formulated "what I want" correctly. What I am trying to say is that row 8 of O should have non-zero collums 8,14,3. Row 9 of O should have non-zero collums 9,15,4

Comment: So row 14 of O should have non-zero collums 14,20,8

Comment: Is your for loop really too slow? Did you profile your program? Don't try to optimize unless it's a bottleneck. For loops are no longer slow in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
  clc; clear;
  C=[8 9 10 14 15 16 20 21 22]';
  R=[14 15 16 20 21 22 25 26 27]';
  L=[3 4 5 8 9 10 14 15 16]';

  %test A
  tic
  for ii=1:100000
    A=zeros(27);
    for i = 1:length(C)
      A(C(i),[R(i) C(i) L(i)]) = [1 2 -1]; 
    end;
  end
  toc

  %optimize
  tic
  for ii=1:100000
    B=zeros(27);
    v=ones(length(C),1);
    B([C C C]+([R C L]-1)*27)=[v v*2 -v];
  end
  toc

  %check
  isequal(A,B)
```

The output is:

```
Elapsed time is 0.854814 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.708940 seconds.

ans =

     1
```

*Thanks for Tommaso Belluzzo's helpful comment!*

Comment: This looks nicer, but performance side it's far from being an optimization. It takes almost twice the time. Also, it seems that the output matrix should be squared 27-by-27.

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Thanks! It seems that `sub2ind` spend too much time, but my new code is an `optimization` now.